# dell 11 300 needs device driver to reinstall Win7/10

Tags: drivers

I have a Dell Inspiron 11 3000 (3168, Tag GS5B0C2) that will not allow the re-installation of Win7 or win10 OS. I have tried all combination of the BIOS Legacy/UEFI - Secure boot (OFF) settings, along with the USB boot memsticks having multiple different versions of Win7 and Win10.

I have even loaded Linux/GPart on to a USB memstick, booted into Linux Gparted and wipe the hard drive clean.

This laptop was given to me because someone, prior to me, had done "something" and it would not boot whatsoever or respond to any keystrokes other than Bios setup(F2) and boot order (F12), and I would get an on screen display of either generic DOS "No boot device" message or a Dell message saying "No boot device"!

As it stands with the hard drive wiped, and a bootable USB memstick loaded with either Win 7 OR WIN 10, the installation process proceeds normally right up to the point where you choose your OS install hard drive and then an error message is displayed that says "A required drive device driver is missing" that does not appear to be on either version (Win7 or Win10) of the bootable USB memstick.

So how do I acquire/supply/provide that driver during either installation process? A second USB drive? and where do I get that driver from?

thanks in advance

Comment: This may sound silly, but try moving the USB drive you are using to another port.  (USB 2.0) Let me know if you still get the error.

Comment: Update your question with the following: MBR or GPT or Unallocated;  The bootable disk FAT32/EFI or something else;  When you attempted to boot to the Windows installation, did the disk show up, in the UEFI boot order;  When you attempted to install Windows 7 were you using a USB 2 or USB 3 device?

Comment: Yes, the "hard drive" does appear, in both the Win7 install and in the Win 10install. I have pics showing the 29gb Hard drive as an install choice, but you can't pics attach here. An info update is the type of "hard drive" for this laptop. I opened this Dell 3168 unit up and there is NO HDD or SSD in this unit, just a permanently mounted, on the motherboard, 32gb MMC chip from Sandisk!

Comment: The OS ([I]Win10 or Win7, UEFI or LEGACY[/I]) it needs to access the "MMC 32gb" chip as a hard drive. I shot an email off to Sandisk ([I]mfr of the MMC32gb Chip[/I]) and they say it was specially made for Dell and they cannot/will not supply the driver to me!

Comment: From Sandisk . . . [I]"You have reached the SanDisk retail support department. The product you are referring to is an OEM product sold directly to top tier laptop manufacturers only. We do not have any retail enduser support for this product. All technical support for this product is provided directly from the laptop manufacturers. Unfortunately, our retail products support team will not be able to assist you with this concern. You will need to contact the laptop manufacturer for assistance. Thank you for choosing Sandisk! Best regards, James SanDisk @ Global Customer Care"[/I]